Creality Halot Mage produces a clicking noise when lowering but not when raising
I have just started hearing a clicking noise when the build plate is lowered on my Halot Mage and not when raising it. I have checked to make sure that nothing is loose and there seems to be grease on it.
I just wanted to know if this is the start of something serious because I also noticed that during the printing, you can see that the model is sticking and pulls hard to release, which I have not seen before either.
Any help would be appreciated as I don't want to end up with a damaged printer that I have only had for a week.

I'm not familiar with that particular printer but if it has an anti-backlash nut on the Z Axis (a second nut on the same screw, spring loaded axially) that could be the source. If so, it's harmless. Lubrication might help but in any case it should not affect printing.
